# Problems with setting OMP_THREAD_LIMIT during runtime (c++ gcc 4.4.7)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Heluuu,

I have a rather large program that I'm attempting to thread. So far, this has been succesful, and the basics are all working as intended.

I now want to do some fancy work with cascading threads in nested mode. Essentially, I want the main parallel region to use any free threads in lower parallel regions.

To detail the current system, the main parallel region starts 10 threads. I have 12 cores, so I can use 2 more threads. There is a second parallel region where some heavy computing happens, and I want the first two threads to reach this point to start a new team there, each with 2 threads. Every new entry to the lower parallel region after this will continue in serial.

So, this should look like the following.
Main region: 10 threads started.
Lower region: 2 new threads started.

Thread 1: 2 threads in lower region.
Thread 2: 2 threads in lower region.
Thread 3-10: 1 thread in lower region.

Please keep in mind that these numbers are for the sake of clarity in providing a concrete description of my situation, and not the absolute and only case in which the program operates.

The code:

```
main() {
    ...
    ...
    omp_set_num_threads(n);
    omp_set_dynamic(x);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            ...
            Compute();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And in Compute

```
bool Compute() {
    ...
    float nThreads = omp_get_thread_limit() - omp_get_num_threads();
    nThreads = ceil(nThreads / omp_get_num_threads());
    omp_set_num_threads((int)nThreads);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        ...
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < nReductSize; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that setting the uppermost limit for the whole program (i.e. OMP_THREAD_LIMIT) only works from outside the program. Using

```
export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=5
```

from the bash command line works great. But I want to do it internally. So far, I've tried

```
putenv("OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=12");
setenv("OMP_THREAD_LIMIT", "12", 1);
```

but when I call omp_get_thread_limit() or getenv("OMP_THREAD_LIMIT") I get wacky return values. Even when I set the variable with export, calling getenv("OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"); returns 0.
So, I would ask for your help in this: How do I properly set OMP_THREAD_LIMIT at runtime?

This is the main function where I set the thread defaults. It is executed well before any threading occurs:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    const char *name = "OMP_THREAD_LIMIT";
    const char *value = "5";
    int overwrite = 1;
    int success = setenv(name, value, overwrite);
    cout << "Var set (0 is success): " << success << endl;
#endif
```

Oh, and setenv reports success in setting the variable.

Compiler says
gcc44 (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)

Flags
CCFLAGS = -c -O0 -fopenmp -g -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -std=c++0x

OpenMP version is 3.0.

Comment: OpenMP will not see your 'putenv'/'setenv' if you did it during runtime (after openmp library is initialized).

Comment: `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` is supposed to enforce externally the upper limit on the size of the thread pool used by the OpenMP runtime. I as a user would be particularly upset if there are provisions in OpenMP that would allow the program to ignore the value of `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` that I have set (e.g. to a value that best matches my hardware) and/or to change it to an arbitrary chosen by the application programmer value.

Comment: I can see how that might be troublesome. But if that is what you perceive me as attempting, you did not read past the first paragraph (the purpose is stated in paragraph 2). I want to use OMP_THREAD_LIMIT as the upper limit for the number of concurrent threads (as it is intended I believe), and disperse the threads available in the most efficient manner I can. Since OMP_THREAD_LIMIT does not appear to be set by default to any practical limitation, I would like to set it within the program to avoid users having to do this manually.

Comment: I do not perceive you attempting anything. I'm just explaining the possible rationale behind the fact that no provisions exist to modify the value of the _thread-limit-var_ ICV from within the program. Note that OpenMP 4.0 introduces the `thread_limit` clause that can modify the value of _thread-limit-var_ but for devices only (e.g. for GPUs or coprocessors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct implementation of OpenMP, and it ignores changes in environment from inside the program. As stated in OpenMP 3.1 Standard, page 159:

> Modifications to the environment variables after the program has started, even if
>   modified by the program itself, are ignored by the OpenMP implementation.

You are doing exactly what is said in this paragraph.

OpenMP allows changing of such parameters only via `omp_set_*` functions, but there are no such function for thread-limit-var ICV:

> However, the settings of some of the ICVs can be modified during the execution of the OpenMP
>   program by the use of the appropriate directive clauses or OpenMP API routines.

I think, you may use `num_threads` clause of `#pragma omp parallel` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the behavior of OpenMP using `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` (or any other `OMP_*` environment variable) is not possible after the program has started; these are intended for use by the user. You could have the user invoke your program through a script that sets `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` and then calls your program, but that's probably not what you need to do in this case.

`OMP_NUM_THREADS`, `omp_set_num_threads`, and the `num_threads` clause are usually used to set the number of threads operating in a region.

Comment: No, you are correct. My expected audience will have a limited understanding of environment variables, and I would much prefer the program be as simple as possible to use. As for omp_set_num_threads and num_threads clause, these are not persistent. I wanted to use OMP_THREAD_LIMIT as a persistent, static value that I could apply to nested parallel sections to make sure that all available threads were used in the most efficient manner, since throwing everything into the first parallel and then having no free threads for the second (nested) parallel is rarely the fastest way to go.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I still don't think that `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` is likely to be the best solution in practice. If you take ten equal chunks of work, and then split two of them in half, that's not likely to improve performance, because the worst-case threads are still just as slow. If your algorithm is effectively doing some kind of load-balancing, then you may as well use omp_set_num_threads calls to explicitly determine which threads will split in the nested region.

Comment: I am doing something like that. If the initial parallel takes 10 iterations, it will use 1,2,3,4,5 or 10 threads, depending on how many are available (since any other number will not reduce the number of total passes in parallel). The remaining threads will be used in the nested region (where the number if iterations can vary wildly). In this second region, threads are attached to the largest iteration sequences. It is however unusual that any one of these would be three times larger than the rest and thus require more than one thread extra to maintain the pace.

Answer (score 0):

It might be offtopic, but you may want to try openmp collapse instead of handcrafting here.